# load static html when click bootstrap menu botton

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Wha't the proper way to load static html when click bootstrap menu?
There is a index.html and content1.html, content2.html  all of them are static.
But, index.html's css is different to content1.html and content2.html.

The layout will like

```
Menu [content1] [content2]
--------------------------
content of content1
```

One stupid solution is:

1. generate all content with the menu bar.
2. index.html is the same as content1.html.
3. the menu bar just use `<a href="content1.html">content1</a>` as link

Cons: the css should modify to the same style.

Is there any better solution?

I'm wonder if it possible to set a `<iframe>` below the menu and dynamic change the content.
Or, Use `<frame>` is better (not limited by iframe size).
But I know `<frame>` is phased out  on html5.

Comment: I'm not following. You use the same css file for all pages and you isolate the different css by either creating custom classes for those page elements or use a class on the parent (body, html, or outer most holder of the different content) and then assign it like so: .content1 .class-name {}

Comment: In fact, I'm build a web page http://dlintw.github.io/gobyexample. The examples are in pygments css. The major index.html is bootstrap3's css.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 ways of doing what you want (there's probably many more).

### The jquery way

You could have content1 / content2 loaded (a)synchronously by a javascript function.
In fact, it's not recomended to load html this way but if your contents have a common structure that can be described in json/xml format then parsed and inserted in your page by a js function, that seems like a smart way to do it.

**For example**
Let's say your page have 2 distinct div areas for simplicity's sake.

You'll make a json (xml is valid too. html is acceptable but not recommended) object representing your page :

```
{
  title:"hello world",
  text:"this is me"
}
```

Then you'll use jquery to load it using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). Once it's done, just insert it like:

```
success= function(data){
  var $content = $("#content");
  $content.empty();
  $("<h1/>").text(data.title).appendTo($content);
  $("<div/>").addClass("myTextStyle").text(data.text).appendTo($content);
}
```

Each request you make then load just the strict minimum you need. Your style is entirely static.

the major drawback is it can become quite complicated if your pages have inconsistent structure. If it's the case, I can only recommand you to use the "classic way" or a javacript framework that'll somewhat ease this process.

### The Bootstrap way

Bootstrap as internally a way to do quite what you want [with tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) by loading everything up front. that's not a dumb thing to do it if your content is lightweight.

### The classic way

Have the page reload on every link, with a backend template parser that recreate the same header with correct content on each page. Not really a modern way to do it but still better than nothing... It's just that you'll have to forget about those nice css transitions you can set with bootstrap.

Comment: Could you show me the jqurey reference method or proper example?  Because there are about 4M bytes in sub pages, So the bootstrap way is not proper in my case.

Comment: I edited my answer to elaborate on jquery async content loading.